# Magento2 - How to add row pattern/dynamic array serialization rows to the custom product page?

Tags: magento2, php, dynamic-rows

**How to add Custom Row and Add Value Dynamic array in serialisation rows?**

*Here I have attached the screenshot:*

[image: <a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnCQ4.png"> Screen shot</a>]

Comment: can you please give more details ? do you want to add row like gift option, attributes ?

Comment: no but like Customizable Options

Comment: ok.. I think ur screenshot is confusing. you want like Customizable Options. which allows to add rows and save by array serialization, right ?

Comment: ok right.......

Comment: so which options you need in dynamic rows. (like title-textbox, options-dropdown and delete button)

Comment: yes ok but this functionality  add after Gift Options

Comment: try this link it's helps you https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/165619/how-to-add-magento2-dynamic-rows-deleteaction/307100#307100