# Add Selected Model Grid Item in Custom UI Component Form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, adminform, ui-form

I've refer the assign source code ui form and with same exact functionality i wanted to add my own store by selection.

I've applied the same code but does not reflect the selected item in the dynamic row component.

For Exact Issue, You can also refer to this link. https://i.stack.imgur.com/JkD7S.jpg

And it should be something like this : [image]

below is my code for the uiform which is `manage_holiday_form.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">manage_holiday_form.manageholiday_form_data_source</item>
        </item>
        <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">General Information</item>
        <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    </argument>
    <settings>
        <buttons>
            <button name="back">
                <url path="*/*/index"/>
                <class>back</class>
                <label translate="true">Back</label>
            </button>
            <button name="reset">
                <class>reset</class>
                <label translate="true">Reset</label>
            </button>
            <button name="save">
                <class>save primary</class>
                <label translate="true">Save</label>
            </button>
        </buttons>
        <namespace>manage_holiday_form</namespace>
        <dataScope>data</dataScope>
        <deps>
            <dep>manage_holiday_form.manageholiday_form_data_source</dep>
        </deps>
    </settings>
    <dataSource name="manageholiday_form_data_source">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <submitUrl path="*/*/save"/>
        </settings>
        <dataProvider class="Vendor\StorePickup\Ui\DataProvider\StoreHolidayDataProvider" name="manageholiday_form_data_source">
            <settings>
                <requestFieldName>entity_id</requestFieldName>
                <primaryFieldName>entity_id</primaryFieldName>
            </settings>
        </dataProvider>
    </dataSource>
    <fieldset name="general">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Holiday Information</label>
        </settings>
        <field name="entity_id" formElement="input">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <dataScope>entity_id</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="holiday_name" formElement="input" sortOrder="20">
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">false</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Holiday Name</label>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field formElement="checkbox" name="is_range" sortOrder="30">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="default" xsi:type="number">0</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <dataScope>is_range</dataScope>
                <label translate="true">Use Holiday In Range</label>
            </settings>
            <formElements>
                <checkbox>
                    <settings>
                        <valueMap>
                            <map name="false" xsi:type="string">0</map>
                            <map name="true" xsi:type="string">1</map>
                        </valueMap>
                        <prefer>toggle</prefer>
                    </settings>
                </checkbox>
            </formElements>
        </field>

        <field name="holiday_date" formElement="date" component="Vendor_StorePickup/js/form/element/date" sortOrder="40">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yy-mm-dd</item>
                        <item name="outputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">yy-mm-dd</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Holiday Date</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <imports>
                    <link name="useSingleDate">${$.parentName}.is_range:checked</link>
                </imports>
                <dataScope>holiday_date</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="holiday_start" formElement="date" component="Vendor_StorePickup/js/form/element/date" sortOrder="50">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yy-mm-dd</item>
                        <item name="outputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">yy-mm-dd</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Holiday Start</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <imports>
                    <link name="shouldDisplay">${$.parentName}.is_range:checked</link>
                </imports>
                <dataScope>holiday_start</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

        <field name="holiday_end" formElement="date" component="Vendor_StorePickup/js/form/element/date" sortOrder="60">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="source" xsi:type="string">store</item>
                    <item name="options" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="dateFormat" xsi:type="string">yy-mm-dd</item>
                        <item name="outputDateFormat" xsi:type="string">yy-mm-dd</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <validation>
                    <rule name="validate-date" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                    <rule name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</rule>
                </validation>
                <dataType>text</dataType>
                <label translate="true">Holiday End</label>
                <visible>false</visible>
                <imports>
                    <link name="shouldDisplay">${$.parentName}.is_range:checked</link>
                </imports>
                <dataScope>holiday_end</dataScope>
            </settings>
        </field>

    </fieldset>
    
    <!-- <fieldset name="assign_stores">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Add Holiday to Store</label>
        </settings>
        <container name="assign_stores_container" >
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">170</item>
                </item>
            </argument>

            <htmlContent name="html_content">
                <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Vendor\StorePickup\Block\Adminhtml\Stores\AssignStores</argument>
            </htmlContent>
        </container>
    </fieldset> -->

    <fieldset name="assign_stores" sortOrder="50">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Assign Stores</label>
            <collapsible>true</collapsible>
            <opened>true</opened>
            <dataScope>assign_stores</dataScope>
        </settings>
        <container name="assign_stores_container" component="Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group" sortOrder="10">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                    <item name="breakLine" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                    <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string" />
                    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" />
                </item>
            </argument>
            <button name="assign_stores_button" template="ui/form/components/button/container">
                <settings>
                    <title translate="true">Assign Stores</title>
                    <dataScope />
                </settings>
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">container</item>
                        <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${$.ns}.${$.ns}.assign_stores.assign_stores_modal</item>
                                <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">toggleModal</item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="additionalForGroup" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="additionalClasses" xsi:type="string">admin__field-medium</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
            </button>
        </container>
        <dynamicRows name="assigned_stores" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/dynamic-rows-grid" sortOrder="20">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="dataProvider" xsi:type="string">data.sources.assign_stores_grid</item>
                    <item name="map" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="Vendor_store_id" xsi:type="string">Vendor_store_id</item>
                        <item name="store_name" xsi:type="string">store_name</item>
                    </item>
                    <item name="identificationDRProperty" xsi:type="string">Vendor_store_id</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
            <settings>
                <label translate="true">Assigned Stores</label>
                <defaultRecord>false</defaultRecord>
                <addButton>false</addButton>
                <deleteProperty>true</deleteProperty>
                <recordTemplate>record</recordTemplate>
                <identificationProperty>Vendor_store_id</identificationProperty>
                <links>
                    <link name="insertData">${ $.provider }:${ $.dataProvider }</link>
                </links>
                <dndConfig>
                    <param name="enabled" xsi:type="boolean">true</param>
                    <param name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/dynamic-rows/cells/dnd</param>
                </dndConfig>
                <columnsHeader>true</columnsHeader>
            </settings>
            <container name="record" component="Magento_Ui/js/dynamic-rows/record">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="isTemplate" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string" />
                        <item name="positionProvider" xsi:type="string">priority</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <field name="Vendor_store_id" formElement="input" sortOrder="10">
                    <settings>
                        <elementTmpl>ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text</elementTmpl>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <dataScope>Vendor_store_id</dataScope>
                        <label translate="true">Store ID</label>
                        <labelVisible>false</labelVisible>
                    </settings>
                </field>
                <field name="store_name" formElement="input" sortOrder="20">
                    <settings>
                        <elementTmpl>ui/dynamic-rows/cells/text</elementTmpl>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <dataScope>store_name</dataScope>
                        <label translate="true">Store Name</label>
                        <labelVisible>false</labelVisible>
                    </settings>
                </field>
                <field name="priority" formElement="input" sortOrder="30">
                    <settings>
                        <elementTmpl>ui/form/element/input</elementTmpl>
                        <dataType>number</dataType>
                        <dataScope>priority</dataScope>
                        <label translate="true">Priority</label>
                        <visible>false</visible>
                    </settings>
                </field>
                <actionDelete name="actionDelete" template="Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi/stock/assign-sources/action-delete">
                    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array" />
                    <settings>
                        <label translate="true">Delete</label>
                        <elementTmpl>Magento_InventoryCatalogAdminUi/stock/assign-sources/action-delete</elementTmpl>
                        <dataType>text</dataType>
                        <componentType>actionDelete</componentType>
                    </settings>
                </actionDelete>
            </container>
        </dynamicRows>
        <modal name="assign_stores_modal">
            <settings>
                <options>
                    <option name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign Stores</option>
                    <option name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="text" xsi:type="string">Cancel</item>
                            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-secondary</item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.name }</item>
                                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">actionCancel</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                        <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                            <item name="text" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Done</item>
                            <item name="class" xsi:type="string">action-primary</item>
                            <item name="actions" xsi:type="array">
                                <item name="0" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">index = assign_stores_grid</item>
                                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">save</item>
                                </item>
                                <item name="1" xsi:type="array">
                                    <item name="targetName" xsi:type="string">${ $.name }</item>
                                    <item name="actionName" xsi:type="string">actionDone</item>
                                </item>
                            </item>
                        </item>
                    </option>
                </options>
            </settings>
            <insertListing name="assign_stores_grid">
                <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="cssclass" xsi:type="string">noclass</item>
                    </item>
                </argument>
                <settings>
                    <autoRender>true</autoRender>
                    <dataScope>assign_stores_grid</dataScope>
                    <ns>storepickup_index_listing</ns>
                    <externalProvider>storepickup_index_listing.storepickup_index_listing_data_source</externalProvider>
                    <selectionsProvider>storepickup_index_listing.storepickup_index_listing.spinner_columns.ids</selectionsProvider>
                    <dataLinks>
                        <imports>false</imports>
                        <exports>true</exports>
                    </dataLinks>
                    <externalFilterMode>true</externalFilterMode>
                </settings>
            </insertListing>
        </modal>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

I've also implemented another way using the custom grid

[image: Custom Grid for store selection]

but this has some deprecated method and mostly,i wanted to reuse the listing grid which I've created so any help on this would be highly appreciated

Comment: try this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/307100/82670

Comment: Thanks, @Msquare for the reply, but actually I wanted to get the selected item data in the dynamic row. that is where the exact issue you can refer here https://imgur.com/a/kbna2vf